# How can i improve image loading time?

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, sdwebimage

[image: sd_setImageWithURL.png]

I am using following code

```
[contestPic sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackSquare.png"]    options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload];
```

There is only one image on screen and called from scrollViewDidEndDecelerating .Even if i download image in background no effects it take same time for first time,Once loaded then second time it take from cache instantly. How can i improve the image loading time for first time?

Comment: You are doing it right! Obviously downloading for the first time will take time, may be image size is big..to make it fast..keep one smaller version of the  image on the server.

Comment: @the_UB yes size is in between 2mb to 3mb. Wait i am doing R/D on Concorde Lib. Suggested by #Divyanshu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use progressive image loading and can use apple's imgaeIO framework for this.this link will help you in this https://www.airpair.com/ios/posts/loading-images-ios-faster-with-progressive-jpegs

Comment: Hi @Divyanshu https://github.com/contentful-labs/Concorde is this demo available in Objective-C.